# Powershell script not running on scheduled task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I can run the script outside and inside the Task Scheduler. But the scheduled tasks will not run the script automatically when triggered. I have tried configuring the Local Security Policies by changing,  User Account Control: Admin Approval Mode for the Built-i Administrator account (Not Defined) - User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode (Disabled) - User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode (Elevate without prompting). This did not work. Any help would be great. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Program/script: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

Add arguments: `-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\moveFiles.ps1`

[image]

[image]

```
Try
{

$Time = Get-Date

if(Test-Path C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\src) {
    "Source exists."
} else {
    Write-Output "This script made a read attempt at [$Time]. Source (C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\src) cannot be found." | out-file C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\KofaxScriptErrorLog.txt -Append
    Exit
}

$IDsrc = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\src\ID - Sub Invoice").Count
$Jsrc  = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\src\J - Sub Invoice").Count
$ORsrc = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\src\OR - Sub Invoice").Count
$OR2   = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\src\OR2 - Sub Invoice").Count
$SCsrc = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\src\SC Invoice").Count
$WAsrc = (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\src\WA - Sub Invoice").Count

# move Kofax ID files to ID folder in Egnyte
If ($IDsrc -ne 0){
Get-ChildItem  -Path "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\src\ID - Sub Invoice" -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop |
    Move-Item -Destination "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\Current Imaging\ID - Sub Invoice" -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    }
# move Kofax J files to J folder in Egnyte 
If ($Jsrc -ne 0){
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\src\J - Sub Invoice" -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop | 
    Move-Item -Destination "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\Current Imaging\J - Sub Invoice" -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    }
# move Kofax OR files to OR folder in Egnyte
If ($ORsrc -ne 0){
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\src\OR - Sub Invoice" -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop | 
    Move-Item -Destination "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\Current Imaging\OR - Sub Invoice" -Force -ErrorAction Stop 
    }
# move Kofax OR2 files to OR2 folder in Egnyte
If ($OR2src -ne 0){
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\src\OR2 - Sub Invoice" -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop | 
    Move-Item -Destination "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\Current Imaging\OR2 - Sub Invoice" -Force -ErrorAction Stop 
    }
# move Kofax SC(multi) files to SC(multi) folder in Egnyte
If ($SCsrc -ne 0){
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\src\SC Invoice" -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop | 
    Move-Item -Destination "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\Current Imaging\SC Invoice" -Force -ErrorAction Stop 
                    }
# move Kofax WA files to WA folder in Egnyte
If ($WAsrc -ne 0){
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\src\WA - Sub Invoice" -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop | 
    Move-Item -Destination "C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\Current Imaging\WA - Sub Invoice" -Force -ErrorAction Stop 
    }       

}   


Catch {

$ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
$FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
    "The script to move files from the Kofax server to Egynte made a run attempt at $Time. Error Details: $ErrorMessage $FailedItem" | out-file C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\KofaxScriptErrorLog.txt -Append
    Break
}

Finally
{

    "This script made a complete read attempt at $Time" | out-file C:\Users\Andersen\Desktop\KofaxScriptLog.txt -Append
}
```

Comment: Member of Logon As Batch?

Comment: Did you try with `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`? Also, you can try to use a batch in "Program/Script :" that starts your Powershell script instead of setting directly your ps1 file to see if the behavior is the same?

Comment: @notjustme Yes I added myself to "Log on as a batch job"

Comment: Was does task sceduler say about the last run result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the Powershell.exe in your schedulded task:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Set this arguments:

```
-noprofile -executionpolicy unrestricted -noninteractive -file "C:\Path\To\MyScript.ps1"
```

Comment: The only change to the arguments shown in the question is to switch from `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` to `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`, which I wouldn't expect to make a difference - except that with `Unrestricted` you can still get a warning prompt if you try to executed downloaded-from-the-web scripts, so `Bypass` is the better choice for unattended execution, assuming you're willing to assume the risks. @DigitalSea, can you explain why this answer solved your problem, and why the arguments in your question didn't work?

Comment: doesn't work for me :(  the server is in the domain, I am RDP to it, can run is script independent but the task scheduler cannot, also no errors :(

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have your execution to unrestricted.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

And add the following action into the `Program\Script` section and click `Yes` on the prompt that appears.

```
PowerShell.exe "& 'C:\LocationFolder\YourScript.ps1'"
```

If you can not set your execution policy to unrestricted just add `-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass` to the above command.